# When deploying a Gatsby site, should I use "gatsby serve" as the deploy script?

Tags: gatsby

I am a little confused about how I serve the static build in the /public folder when I am deploying. I am thinking about using 'gatsby serve' but it mentions this is to be used before deployment so I am confused. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gatsby serve` serves the production build of your site in a development environment (locally or on a staged server). But the command in charge of building your site for a automated deploy (CI/CD) is `gatsby build`, which is the one that creates a `/public` folder that needs to be stored in your server.

In plain words: `gatsby serve` allows you to see your built site locally (by default at localhost in the port 9000, `localhost:9000`) but the command that needs to be triggered to build your site in a deployment is `gatsby build`, because you will be storing the `/public` folder in the `/www` or `/public` of your hosting server.

From [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/#serve):

> `gatsby serve`
>
> Serves the production build of your site for testing
> prior to deployment. Should be run from the root of your project.

Spot the *for testing prior to deployment*

> `gatsby build`
>
> Compiles your site for production so it can be deployed. Should be run from the root of your project.

To serve your site in your server, you just need to place the `/public` folder (created by `gatsby build`) in the public folder of your hosting server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you mean by "place the /public fodler in the public folder of your hosting server"? By default the node server for our hosting runs npm run build then npm run start - will this automatically serve the production site? Thanks so much :)

Comment: Yes, if your CI/CD hosting runs the `build` command, it should be automatically deployed, but this technical details will rely on your server, and it manages those tasks. I meant that if you imagine a super manual deploy (FTP for example), you can deploy your site running a `gatsby build` and copying the `/public` folder content and pasting it in the public folder of the server (normally called `/www` or `/public`).